# How do I load my factory before doing anything in the controller in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have a factory setup that connects to socket.io.

Whenever I setup a controller, I reference this factory but it seems like my controller is doing things before the factory is done loading.  How do I make sure that the factory is done doing its thing before doing anything in the controller?  Right now the only thing I can think of is to wrap everything that depends on the factory in a 1 second timeout, but I really don't like that.

Comment: Please make sure that no asynchronous process was executed when you initialize the factory. In my opinion, factories/services should provide methods that will be call in controllers, not to run them by itself automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could broadcast an event from your factory, like so:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast("factoryIsDone");
```

Note: for it to work, `$rootScope` must be injected in your factory

And catch it in your controller:

```
$scope.$on("factoryIsDone",function(){...});
```